# Declare vector inside loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector

Let's say I have the following code:

```
void Idle()
{
   vector<cv::Point> vec;
   FillVector(vec);
}
```

Idle function runs several times throughout the program. I fill the `vector` with points using `FillVector` and `vec.push_back(...)` and passing `vec` by reference. The `vector` always gets the same size after the `FillVector` function (e.g 10 points).
The question is: Do I have to clear the `vector` before going again in the `Idle` in order to reuse it with the same size but different points each time ? Or the fact that I declare again `vec` with the same name means that it is re-initialized with zero objects ?

Comment: You will get a new vector instance every time `Idle()` is called.

Comment: It has to be declared each time. Once `Idle` ends the vector will go out of scope and no longer exist - so the next time you call `Idle` you have to  create it again.

Comment: When `Idle()` finishes the vector is destroyed, since it goes out of scope. But be careful, you may have memory leaks if `cv::Point` allocates memory dynamically and don't free it on the destructor.

Comment: **–1** The function declaration is syntactically invalid → this is **not real code**.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, if it's put inside a `class Idle { /* ... */ };` declaration, the code is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, any time you use curly brace, you've created a new scope (in this case a function scope). The variables declared in that scope will be deleted when you leave it; in particular, your vector object will be created and deleted every time.

Comment: This is true only to values created on stack. Variables created dynamically (via new/malloc) will not be deleted when out of scope. Though in this example variable would be overwritten by new vector which would lead to memory leak.

Comment: Is it possible to create variables on the heap? For example, if I write `Foo *f = new Foo();` I may have allocated memory on the heap, but my variable is a pointer to that memory. `f` will get deleted when I leave the scope, and I have to pass its value back somehow to keep its value. Maybe I've confused my wording between "variable" and "object", but I am fairly certain, in C++, the destructor will be called before leaving the scope for anything declared there.

Comment: If you want to preserve pointer to that memory/object, you have to save it. This can be done in milion ways (return pointer, store it in place which will live longer that current scope etc.). Also have in mind, that `Foo* f = new Foo();` will "create two variables": `f` - pointer on stack, which will be destroyed when out of scope and some unnamed variable on heap, which can be accesed by any pointer to it. You might think of it as just the memory, but it won't be destroyed unless you explicitly call `delete f` function.

Comment: I think you're mistaken as to what a variable is, at least in the C/C++ sense. A variable is a declared symbol recognized by the compiler; `Foo *f = new Foo()` does not create two variables, only one: the pointer `f`. The memory it points to doesn't constitute a new variable. See, for example, the [C FAQ discussion of malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/malloc1.html).

Comment: Yes, you're right, but i was talking more semantics then syntax, to show OP (and you) that destroying pointer doesn't calls pointed object's destructor. `The variables declared in that scope will be deleted when you leave it` - this can lead newbie to bad conclusions. Also its simpler point of view for someone new to language and i think we can both agree that OP is such person. It might be one variable from C++ compiler PoV, but there are two from semantic point of view - (1) pointer, and (2) Foo object allocated on stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to variable scoping.
Here you declare a `vector` that will be stored on the stack. The lifetime of your vector is from its declaration to the point you leave your `Idle` function.

Thus, in your case, it is safe to assume that the vector is "cleared" (in fact it is a different vector).

Answer (score 0):

`vec` is a local variable in `Idle` so, each time you leave the function it will be **destroyed**. Each time you call `Idle` a **new vector** will be created. 
If you want to preserve `vec` between `Idle` calls declare it as a `static`.

Comment: `Idle` can not be a function in C, since it uses C++ templates. And it can not be a function in C++, since it's syntactically invalid in C++. I.e. `Idle` is not a function.

Comment: Good point, it hard to say  what `Idle()` exactly is. I assumed it is a function/method. (Maybe it was my mistake).